# Make deduction result contain 2 decimal places

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm importing a price from a database. 
The price value originally contains 2 decimal places.

From each price value, I want to deduct the relevant shipping value, and keep the result with 2 decimal places as well.

**Code:**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $product_name = $row['Name'];

    $keys = array_keys($item_array, $product_name);
    foreach ($keys as $x) 

    $product[$x]["total_price"] = $row['price'];
    $product[$x]["shipping"] = $row['shipping'];
    $product[$x]["base_price"] = ($row['price']-$row['shipping']); // Calculation
```

Currently, I'm not sure how it works, but when:

`$product[1]["price"] = 99.90`

And the relevant shipping that I'm deducting is `0`,
The result is `99.9` instead of `99.90`.

What's the best practice to keep two decimal points?

Answer (score 2):

`99.90` is a formatted output of `99.9`. To obtain constant format of numbers, you have to output-it through `number_format` in this way:

```
echo number_format ( $product[1]["price"], 2 );
```

the argument `2`is the number of decimals to be printed.

**Please note:** the result of this function is a **string,** not a number; the function is intended to print output, not for math.

In the official [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) you can see how to set other parameters, like the separator for the decimal point and the thousands separator.

Comment: But how can I format `$product[$x]["base_price"]` to be formatted in advance, so that in every instance that I echo it, it will be formatted right away?

Comment: Yes, if you don't make calculations with it. So, you can do `$product[1]["price"] = number_format( $product[1]["price"], 2 )`

Comment: money_format or NumberFormatter::formatCurrency might be better

Comment: @rjdown can you elaborate?

Comment: They are more suited for currency formatting. For example, Japanese Yen have no decimal places, so you wouldn't want to blindly add them. These methods will also add the appropriate currency symbol in the correct location. A good example would be the Canadian dollar symbol, which changes from the left side to the right side depending on your locale (e.g. en_CA or fr_CA)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format numbers & strings.

in your case you can do

`$product[$x]["base_price"] = sprintf("%.2f",($row['price']-$row['shipping']));`

Comment: would this automatically print it? since at this stage I don't want to print anything, just to create a new `$product[$x]["base_price"]` variable for each row in the database.

Comment: note that in the db it might stay without the 0 as your db engine might ignore it but in the output you can add this line

Comment: @Gal It's print, yes it's print! (See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)) Use `sprintf` to return a variable instead of print-it

Comment: @fusion3k you're right,I edited my answer.sorry about that.

Comment: @rockyraw that depends on you